# for in combination with html forms

Tags: php, html

I want to provide different options in a html form, with a php for loop, but the loop gets all the time stuck. Thanks in advance for helping me out.

```
<select name="position">
 <?php 
   for($i=1;$i<10;$i++) {
    echo "<option value= . $i >$i</option>";
   }
 ?>
```

Comment: echo '<option value="' . $i . '">' . $i . '</option>';

Answer (score 0):

if you are use double quotes  can without . Operator

```
<select name="position">

<?php
   for($i=1;$i<10;$i++) {
    echo "<option value= ' $i '>$i</option>";
   }
?>
</select>
```

Answer (score -2):

You look like you are missing the quotes in the value tag.

```
echo "<option value= \"$i\" >$i</option>";
```